# Every closed ideal of $C^{\star}-$ algebra is self adjoint.

Tags: ideals, c-star-algebras

I am looking for a proof of the following well known result.

> Every closed ideal $I$ of $C^{\star}-$ algebra is self adjoint that is if $x \in I$ then $x^{\ast} \in I$

Any reference or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $J$ be a two sided ideal of the $C^{\star}$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Consider the $C^{\star}$ subalgebra $\mathcal{B}=J\cap J^{\star}$. Let $\{e_i \}_{i\in I}$ be an approximate identity of positive elements with $\|e_i\|\leq 1$ for $\mathcal{B}$. Show the net $a^{\star}e_{i}$ converges to $a^{\star}$.

Comment: Can you please say why the mentioned net converges to $a^*$ ?

Comment: Using the $C^{\star}$ property $$\|a^\star -a^\star e_i\|^2=\|(a^\star-a^\star e_i )^\star (a^\star-a^\star e_i )\|$$ The right side is bounded by $2\|aa^\star-aa^\star e_i\|$ but this term goes to zero because $aa^\star\in \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Where do you use the bound on norm $e_i$?

Comment: To obtain the bound for the right side, in fact using triangle inequality you find it is least or equal than $$\|aa^\star-aa^\star e_i\|+\|e_i(aa^\star-aa^\star e_i)\|$$ here you use the bound on $\|e_i\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Consult Theorem BA.4.1 (page 108) in

Barnes, Murphy, Smyth, West: Riesz and Fredholm theory in Banach algebras.

Comment: The proof is not given there.